# Nginx reverse proxy.. dynamic hostname with header key and value or url path

Tags: nginx, networking, dynamic, proxy, routes

I have got some nginx problem.I hope you will help me to solve this problem.

There are sevral servers

1. User PC internet networked;
2. Nginx proxy, hostnamed "nginxproxy", located in internal network, and it has only server which has Public IP "1.1.1.1" but jumphost, 8090 listen.
3. server1 hostnamed "tomcat1" located in internal network (only has private IP "70.1.1.1")
4. server2 hostnamed "tomcat2" located in internal network (only has private IP "70.1.1.2")

and 5, 6, ... There are more servers hostnamed apache1, apache2, redis1 etc...

Now my client wants to send http request call to server located in internal network directly. but it is not possible (because there don't have Public ips..) so the call has to passed in to nginx proxy first.

I just wander that when i call request from user pc, destination server hostname put on the request's header or url, the nginx can  parse it and combine to there destination in internal network?

for example i call like this,

```
     http://nginxproxy:1888/[destination hostname]/[path, files like index.html, some keys and values.&k1=v1. etc....]
```

i hope nginx pass and convert it and call there destination host like this

```
     http://[destination hostname]:8888/[path, files like index.html, some keys and values.&k1=v1. etc....]
```

i tried to do this. there were some errors..

error log printed 
"localhost could not be resolved (10060: Operation timed out), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /localhost/8080/index"

```
server {
    listen       1888;
    server_name  localhost;

    location  ~^\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) {
    proxy_pass http://$1:$2/$3;
    }



}
```

and one more..

in the java code, 
i set like this

```
    import org.apache.http.HttpMessage;

    HttpMessage request;
    request.addHeader("destinationHost", "tomcat2");
    request.addHeader("destinationPort", "8888");
```

and call to this url

```
     http://nginxproxy:1888/[path, files like index.html, some keys and values.&k1=v1. etc....]
```

can nginx convert url to

```
    http://tomcat2:8888/[path, files like index.html, some keys and values.&k1=v1. etc....]
```

and pass to there??

if so, how can i set nginx.conf

thank you so much and have a nice day..